# Android dictionary application

Tags: android

I wanted to develop an application on top of a dictionary i.e. an application that uses dictionary as a part of it.Is their any dictionary application available in the market for this purpose?Application which come under GPL is preferable.Also those which uses local database instead of using network  connection is preferable.

If not,is there any dictionary database available in the market on the top of which a dictionary application can be developed which can then be used for said purpose?

Hope I am clear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a program that you will allow the user to export their dictionary, from that you may be able to do what you want.

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.usr.dict.mgr

More over, you can just reference the built in `UserDictionary`, and use a `ContentProvider` to query through the data.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/UserDictionary.html

Comment: But I needed a dictionary database and not simply a datastructure to handle the dictionary.

Comment: So you want to make your own dictionary database? I don't understand what you are talking about the `UserDictionary.Words` has a list of all the user-defined words.

Comment: "UserDictionary.Words has a list of all the user-defined words."Oh! great!I didn't saw that.Thanks a lot for ur generous reply.

Comment: @hwrdprkns hi is there any way to check the string against dictionary library cos the Word class will return the user-defined words only .Please correct me if i am wrong. thanks