# How to check whether given string is a word

Tags: java, android, string, dictionary

Hello I am developing a word game where i want to check the user input as valid word or not 
please suggest the way i can check the given string in android.

Eg . String s = "asfdaf" 
i want to check whether its a valid one.

Comment: you need to have a dictionary for that ... and then make a match..

Comment: What do you mean by "valid one"? Is that mean, the given word has a meaning or not? Are you using a dictionary in your application?

Comment: in android you can have dict in form of a file or a sqlite database..

Comment: @AnujAroshA  i dont want use dictionary db. is there any way to use the built in dictionary library

Comment: @Mahesh have you try with [UserDictionary] (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/UserDictionary.html) If not, I think you can find a source of Dictionary that has GPL, just like [UDM] (http://udm.adrianvintu.com/)

Answer (score 8):

There are many possible solutions to this some are the following

Use a web Dictionary API

[https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/](http://developer.dictionary.com/)

http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/12/on-googles-unofficial-dictionary-api.html

http://www.dictionaryapi.com/

if you would prefer a local solution

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

class WordChecker {
    public static boolean check_for_word(String word) {
        // System.out.println(word);
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "/usr/share/dict/american-english"));
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (str.indexOf(word) != -1) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(check_for_word("hello"));
    }
}
```

this uses the local word list found on all Linux systems to check for the word

Comment: @mohammedalisunasara I fixed it, it should work now.

Comment: Bro it is still not working it is directly send to return false

Comment: @mohammedalisunasara well mine works as with the code I've just put up. This depends on the /usr/share/dict/american-english though

Answer (score 6):

First, download a word list from for example [`here`](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/blob/master/words.txt). Place it in the root directory of your project. Use the following code to check whether a [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is part of the word list or not:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Dictionary
{
    private Set<String> wordsSet;

    public Dictionary() throws IOException
    {
        Path path = Paths.get("words.txt");
        byte[] readBytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        String wordListContents = new String(readBytes, "UTF-8");
        String[] words = wordListContents.split("\n");
        wordsSet = new HashSet<>();
        Collections.addAll(wordsSet, words);
    }

    public boolean contains(String word)
    {
        return wordsSet.contains(word);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd store a dictionary and do a lookup in there. If the word is present in the dictionary, it's valid.

You can find a some clues on how to do this here:
[Android dictionary application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301125/android-dictionary-application)

Comment: is there any way to use built-in dictionary feature of android

Comment: yes kind of thing i want but it will give me only user defined words only :(

Answer (score 1):

> zeitue said:
>
> ```
> import java.io.BufferedReader;
> import java.io.FileReader;
> import java.io.IOException;
>
> class WordChecker {
>     public static boolean check_for_word(String word) {
>         // System.out.println(word);
>         try {
>             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
>                 "/usr/share/dict/american-english"));
>             String str;
>             while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
>                 if (str.indexOf(word) != -1) {
>                     return true;
>                 }
>             }
>             in.close();
>         } catch (IOException e) {
>         }
>
>         return false;
>     }
>
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         System.out.println(check_for_word("hello"));
>     }
> }
> ```

but this will only work on linux. if you want this same thing on a mac change the path from

```
/usr/share/dict/american-english
```

to

```
/usr/share/dict/web2
```

I have not tried this on windows but if someone knows comment below

Answer (score 0):

```
if(s.equals("word from dictionary in loop"){
    //action
}
```

and it's also good to

```
s = s.toLowerCase();
```

so there would be no matter how "pokemon" is the entry word

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code for basic validation

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputValidation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input;
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter the input");
            Scanner s = new  Scanner(System.in);

            input = s.next();
            if(input.matches(".*\\d.*")){
                System.out.println(" Contains digit only");
            } else{
                System.out.println(" Only String/words found");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```