# How to validate an ENGLISH WORD entered by the user - ANDROID

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm developing a word-building game (similar to scrabble) that takes a user's input and checks whether it is a valid word or not. First, I thought of using an offline dictionary database with `SQLite`.

But later I realized that there's a built-in dictionary (that predicts the words that are being entered in the text fields).

Is there any way that I can use this built-in dictionary to validate words entered in my app?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Whether possible or not, this seems to be a valid question...

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428401/android-word-validation?rq=1)

Comment: Downvotes might be based on: no signs of prior research ... and not much evidence of "own work". The question reads more or less like "I have a great idea; please somebody else show me how to do it".

Comment: Who predicts the words entered in text fields varies. It is usually Google, via google Keyboard or google search and i don't know how much of that you can access.

Comment: @Jagermeister -  I **did** try to find the solution on my own. But none of the articles I found answered my question. This is my first question and Next time I'll try to do a better research. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @BearArmatis - Yeah I've checked that post earlier but all the answers suggested that using a dictionary database is better. Also I was hoping that I might get updated answers as that question was asked an year ago :) .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perhaps what you are searching Android Spelling Cheker, here is an [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_spelling_checker.htm).

Comment: I believe that is not the answer, Spell checker is a global thing - no one wants to install spellchecker instead of game! He needs dictionary, a lot could be found on the net.