# Capitalize String according to dictionary

Tags: java, string, dictionary

I want to programmatically capitalize words in a String depending on a dictionary (!). It should be like the [Java variable and method naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java) in [`CamelCase`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase). Given is a string in all lowercase. Find the most likely Java convention casing.

I made a start [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36519492/3764804) with an existing dictionary file and a class for checking whether a given `String` is part of the dictionary or not. The difficulty is to find the right or most likely [`substrings`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)). How would you improve this?

```
public String capitalizeWords(String text)
{
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    StringBuilder capitalizedWordBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    int firstWordLength = text.length();
    int beginIndex = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        String subText = text.substring(beginIndex, firstWordLength);

        if (contains(subText))
        {
            String word = capitalizeFirst(subText);
            capitalizedWordBuilder.append(word);
            beginIndex += word.length();
            firstWordLength = text.length() + 1;
        }

        firstWordLength--;

        if (beginIndex == firstWordLength && beginIndex == text.length())
        {
            String capitalized = capitalizedWordBuilder.toString();
            return deCapitalizeFirst(capitalized);
        }
    }
}

private String capitalizeFirst(String text)
{
    if (text.length() < 2)
    {
        return text;
    }

    return Character.toUpperCase(text.charAt(0)) + text.substring(1);
}

private String deCapitalizeFirst(String text)
{
    if (text.length() < 2)
    {
        return text;
    }

    return Character.toLowerCase(text.charAt(0)) + text.substring(1);
}
```

**Example runs:**
javaisawesome -> javaIsAwesome (**Good**)
thisisastring -> thisIsAstrIng (**Bad**)

Comment: Good luck. Why wouldn't it be `thIsIsAString`? Or, if you add the words `I` and `his` `tHIsIsAStrIng`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch:
It's not clearly defined but if no valid word is left it's obvious that the solution so far is wrong...