# Getting the least amount of sub words

Tags: java, nlp, text-segmentation

Solution by [`Dávid Horváth`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36521440/3764804) adapted to return the biggest smallest word:

```
import java.util.*;

public class SubWordsFinder
{
    private Set<String> words;

    public SubWordsFinder(Set<String> words)
    {
        this.words = words;
    }

    public List<String> findSubWords(String word) throws NoSolutionFoundException
    {
        List<String> bestSolution = new ArrayList<>();
        if (word.isEmpty())
        {
            return bestSolution;
        }
        long length = word.length();
        int[] pointer = new int[]{0, 0};
        LinkedList<int[]> pointerStack = new LinkedList<>();
        LinkedList<String> currentSolution = new LinkedList<>();
        while (true)
        {
            boolean backtrack = false;
            for (int end = pointer[1] + 1; end <= length; end++)
            {
                if (end == length)
                {
                    backtrack = true;
                }
                pointer[1] = end;
                String wordToFind = word.substring(pointer[0], end);
                if (words.contains(wordToFind))
                {
                    currentSolution.add(wordToFind);
                    if (backtrack)
                    {
                        if (bestSolution.isEmpty() || (currentSolution.size() <= bestSolution.size() && getSmallestSubWordLength(currentSolution) > getSmallestSubWordLength(bestSolution)))
                        {
                            bestSolution = new ArrayList<>(currentSolution);
                        }
                        currentSolution.removeLast();
                    } else if (!bestSolution.isEmpty() && currentSolution.size() == bestSolution.size())
                    {
                        currentSolution.removeLast();
                        backtrack = true;
                    } else
                    {
                        int[] nextPointer = new int[]{end, end};
                        pointerStack.add(pointer);
                        pointer = nextPointer;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (backtrack)
            {
                if (pointerStack.isEmpty())
                {
                    break;
                } else
                {
                    currentSolution.removeLast();
                    pointer = pointerStack.removeLast();
                }
            }
        }
        if (bestSolution.isEmpty())
        {
            throw new NoSolutionFoundException();
        } else
        {
            return bestSolution;
        }
    }

    private int getSmallestSubWordLength(List<String> words)
    {
        int length = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for (String word : words)
        {
            if (word.length() < length)
            {
                length = word.length();
            }
        }

        return length;
    }

    public class NoSolutionFoundException extends Exception
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    }
}
```

---

I have a `String` contained of regular English words in lowercase. Let's say this `String` is already decomposed into a `List` of all possible subwords:

```
public List<String> getSubWords(String text)
{
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int startingIndex = 0; startingIndex < text.length() + 1; startingIndex++)
    {
        for (int endIndex = startingIndex + 1; endIndex < text.length() + 1; endIndex++)
        {
            String subString = text.substring(startingIndex, endIndex);

            if (contains(subString))
            {
                words.add(subString);
            }
        }
    }

    Comparator<String> lengthComparator = (firstItem, secondItem) ->
    {
        if (firstItem.length() > secondItem.length())
        {
            return -1;
        }

        if (secondItem.length() > firstItem.length())
        {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    };

    // Sort the list in descending String length order
    Collections.sort(words, lengthComparator);

    return words;
}
```

How do I find the least amount of subwords that form the original String?

**For example:**

```
String text = "updatescrollbar";
List<String> leastWords = getLeastSubWords(text);
System.out.println(leastWords);
```

**Output:**

```
[update, scroll, bar]
```

I'm not sure how to iterate through all possibilities since they change depending on the chosen words. A start would be something like this:

```
public List<String> getLeastSubWords(String text)
{
    String textBackup = text;
    List<String> subWords = getSubWords(text);
    System.out.println(subWords);
    List<List<String>> containing = new ArrayList<>();

    List<String> validWords = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String subWord : subWords)
    {
        if (text.startsWith(subWord))
        {
            validWords.add(subWord);
            text = text.substring(subWord.length());
        }
    }

    // Did we find a valid words distribution?
    if (text.length() == 0)
    {
        System.out.println(validWords.size());
    }

    return null;
}
```

**Note:**
This is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519693/capitalize-string-according-to-dictionary) question.

Comment: 1st you extract a list of all words contained in `text`? 2nd you try to find the least amount of words, that make up that string (exactly?)? What if there is no solution? I think it would be much easier doing both tasks at the same time.

Comment: It is much more better to use an indexed collection like `TreeSet` instead of `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: The algorithm below can be much more efficient, if you reverse the inner foreach. In this case, longer words will be checked first.

---

This is a typical situation for a backtracking algorithm.

Store your words in a `TreeSet`, and implement this algorithm:

1. Set start and end pointer to `0`. Create a stack to store previous versions of the pointer.
2. Generate substrings from the start pointer, while increase end pointer, and find for a known word. If a word found, store it in an array, and add the word's length to the start pointer, push this pointer to the stack. If no known word found or the last character was reached, set the start and end pointers to the previous value popped from the stack (backtracking). Repeat 2. step.
3. To find the least amount of subwords, you must store previous best solution, and compare its word count with the current solution's word count.

Below is an example implementation. It contains some experiment of optimization: no recursion, backtrack on a bad branch etc. You can add more optimization (for example, tracking used start positions, or look up for possible subword start positions), but it is probably unnecessary, if the parameter is a not too long word.

```
public class SubWordFinder {

    private TreeSet<String> words = new TreeSet<String>();

    public SubWordFinder(Collection<String> words) {
        this.words.addAll(words);
    }

    public List<String> findSubWords(String word) throws NoSolutionFoundException {
        List<String> bestSolution = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (word.isEmpty()) {
            return bestSolution;
        }
        long length = word.length();
        int[] pointer = new int[]{0, 0};
        LinkedList<int[]> pointerStack = new LinkedList<int[]>();
        LinkedList<String> currentSolution = new LinkedList<String>();
        while (true) {
            boolean backtrack = false;
            for (int end = pointer[1] + 1; end <= length; end++) {
                if (end == length) {
                    backtrack = true;
                }
                pointer[1] = end;
                String wordToFind = word.substring(pointer[0], end);
                if (words.contains(wordToFind)) {
                    currentSolution.add(wordToFind);
                    if (backtrack) {
                        if (bestSolution.isEmpty() || currentSolution.size() < bestSolution.size()) {
                            bestSolution = new ArrayList<String>(currentSolution);
                        }
                        currentSolution.removeLast();
                    } else if (!bestSolution.isEmpty() && currentSolution.size() == bestSolution.size()) {
                        currentSolution.removeLast();
                        backtrack = true;
                    } else {
                        int nextStart = end;
                        int[] nextPointer = new int[]{nextStart, nextStart};
                        pointerStack.add(pointer);
                        pointer = nextPointer;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (backtrack) {
                if (pointerStack.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    currentSolution.removeLast();
                    pointer = pointerStack.removeLast();
                }
            }
        }
        if (bestSolution.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NoSolutionFoundException();
        } else {
            return bestSolution;
        }
    }

    public class NoSolutionFoundException extends Exception {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    }

}
```

Tests:

```
public class SubWordFinderTest {

    @Test
    public void generalTest() throws SubWordFinder.NoSolutionFoundException {
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        words.add("ab");
        words.add("abc");
        words.add("cd");
        words.add("cde");
        words.add("de");
        words.add("e");
        SubWordFinder finder = new SubWordFinder(words);
        assertEquals(new ArrayList<String>(), finder.findSubWords(""));
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList("ab", "cde"), finder.findSubWords("abcde"));
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList("cd", "cde"), finder.findSubWords("cdcde"));
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList("abc", "cd"), finder.findSubWords("abccd"));
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList("de", "e", "e", "e", "e"), finder.findSubWords("deeeee"));
        try {
            finder.findSubWords("ae");
            fail();
        } catch (SubWordFinder.NoSolutionFoundException e) {
        }
        try {
            finder.findSubWords("abcccd");
            fail();
        } catch (SubWordFinder.NoSolutionFoundException e) {
        }
        try {
            finder.findSubWords("abcdex");
            fail();
        } catch (SubWordFinder.NoSolutionFoundException e) {
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void dictionaryTest() throws IOException, SubWordFinder.NoSolutionFoundException {
        String resourceDir = "/path_to_resources";
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResource(resourceDir + "/20k.txt").openStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            words.add(line);
        }
        SubWordFinder finder = new SubWordFinder(words);
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList("bromide", "freshet"), finder.findSubWords("bromidefreshet"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts :)
I tried your code but it didn't return a correct result. With my example input `updatescrollbar` it would return `[u, p, d, a, t, e, s, c, r, o, l, l, bar]` with the dictionary sub words list which is clearly not a least words solution...

Comment: As you can see, I have a certain amount of passed subtests. Please attach your dictionary and/or your failed test case.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot that if there are multiple solutions with the same amount of subwords the one with the longest shortest word should be chosen. So `[update, scroll, bar]` would be preferred over `[update, sc, rollbar]` since `sc` is only 2 characters in comparison to `bar` having 3. This would be another refinement of the method. Anyway, I got it. See the first post

Comment: If you have more requirements, use a custom `Comparator` instead of `currentSolution.size() < bestSolution.size()`. While this comparator is compatible with the original requirement (word count), bad branch exit optimization can be also kept.

Comment: In retrospect, the algorithm can be much more efficient, if you reverse the inner foreach. In this case longer words will be checked first. Of course, your additional comparison is still required.

Comment: Indeed, longer words are desired in general

Answer (score 0):

That is asking for a lot of scenario possibilities.

Your example (`updatescrollbar`) has already `up date ate update scroll bar` and is still pretty easy, but what if you have a word which has as subwords which leave you with a single character possibility at the end of the string.

So to go through this you will have to iterate multiple times over your list of subwords, keeping track of the current shortest valid version matching your text, and keep iterating until you tried all variations.

You can reduce the number of variations for example by using an algorithm which takes the remaining to be matched space into account:

- Sort your subwords on length, and try to fit the text with the longest words first: length subword possible=text-/- matched text.
  This would use a contains, so the text to be matched still can be before and after already matched words: Use an array for your text so that it is easier to keep track of the matched text.